# How to get Shipping Method Title Name in order confirmation email in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order, shipping-methods

I have set up shipping method in Magento admin Panel. like see below image-

[image]

This shipping method has set Title and Method Name as shown in above image.

When I get Order Confirmation Email after successfull checkout I get Shipping Method two times, see this image below-

[image]

how can I show shipping method title here only one time.

Comment: Can you show us your transcational email template code, please ?

Comment: Isn´t that because you have the title and method name there? So it actually shows the title and method name in the email?! If you change the title then you can check if thats true or not

Comment: I have removed value from Title field, still it is showing shipping methode twice time. I check my email template and I see this shipping method is coming from this variable `var order.getShippingDescription()`.

Comment: Can you give us an update?

Answer (score 2):

As @Thomas said in the comment, it could  be because of your title and method both having same value.

```
Shipping via: Carrier Title
Method name
```

Either keep blank `Title` field in admin or give it some other name to make method name appear only once.